# Keeping current running thread instance in a map?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee

I am using spring and java. I have below configuration.

### applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

### PrintTask.java

```
public class PrintTask implements Runnable{

    String name;

    public PrintTask(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(name + " is running", name + " is running");
        Container.containerMap.put(this, map);
        System.out.println(name + " is running");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(name + " is running");
    }

}
```

### PrintTaskTest.java

```
public class PrintTaskTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) context.getBean("taskExecutor");
        taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 1"));
        taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 2"));
        taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 3"));
        taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 4"));
        taskExecutor.execute(new PrintTask("Thread 5"));

        //check active thread, if zero then shut down the thread pool
        for (;;) {
            int count = taskExecutor.getActiveCount();
            System.out.println("Active Threads : " + count);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                taskExecutor.shutdown();
                break;
            }
        }

        }
}
```

### container.java

```
public class Container {

    public static Map<PrintTask, Map<String,String>> containerMap = new HashMap<PrintTask, Map<String,String>>();

}
```

My requirement is :

I have several threads calling the same logic. In my example PrintTask is being called by 5 threads. Whenever the logic is called, i have to store values in a map as key value pairs.

```
Key = current Theread object
value = some Map
```

Again when required i can pass the current thread and get its values from the map.

Am i doing in right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to comment on what is correct without understand *why* you are doing this. It strikes me that your `Map` of values should be moved outside the `run` method, otherwise it will just be filled with the data of one thread. You could make it a static class field, ensuring that you synchronize access to it... Again, it depends why you are doing this!

Comment: @Jones, My idea is, here i have several threads, i just need to store each thread object and some values into map. Again i should be able to get the map entries by passing thread object. My idea is actual print taks class does some validation logic. I have to save all validation failures into a Map with that thread object. Again i should get those failure entries from map using the same thread object.Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use `Callable` instead of `Runnable` and then use the `submit` function on the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. That way you can determine if a thread already finished and get its results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Container {
    private final static Map<PrintTask, Map<String, String>> values = new HashMap<>();

    public static void putTaskToMap(PrintTask key, Map<String, String> values) {
        synchronized(values) {
            values.put(key, values);
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getValues(PrintTask key) {
        syncronized (values) {
        Map<String, String> retVal = values.get(key);
        if(retVal == null) {
             retVal = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());
             values.put(retVal);
        }
        return retVal;
        }
    }
}

public class PrintTask extends Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    Map<String, String> map = Container.getValues(this);
    map.put(name + " is running", name + " is running");
    System.out.println(name + " is running");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(name + " is running");
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    Map<String, String> values = Container.getValues(this);
    // the values here will always be the _same_ Map containing the same contents as the one in run.
}
```

The important parts are:

1. that you have the `Map` outside of your `run` method.
2. that your `Map` is not instance bound (either it is `static` or it is accessed through a shared instance of another class)
3. that every access to that `Map` is `synchronized`. (either through use of `Collections.synchronizedMap` or throuh a `synchronized` keyword in the method head.)

Have a good read of the documentation:

1. [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)
2. [Collections.synchronizedMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

Comment: my plan is i have a class with static map.inside the logic class i can directly put and get the values from the map right? as belo..Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(name + " is running", name + " is running");
        Container.containerMap.put(this, map); to get Container.containerMap.get(this);

Comment: Yesno. You have two Maps. ONE containing the connection PrintTask - values TWO the values themselves. The FIRST needs to be outside of the PrintTask Instance (see important part 2). The SECOND you get at the beginning of you `run` method and put back at the end of it.

Comment: YEs..That is what am going to do..I am going to keep a static map in a separate class. will there be any issues with that? Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 I'll edit my answer. Please stand by.

Comment: @user755806 See my edit. It is VERY important to understand what the `synchronized` keyword does and how it works. Also it is very important to understand `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. You MUST read the documentation before proceeding or you will get headaches.

Comment: @user755806 I have put the links to the documentation into my answer.

Comment: plz could you tell me what is syncronized (values) ?

Comment: Also, u have used syncronized (values) inside getValues() ? why is it required? Please explain me.

Comment: @user755806 Please see the linked documentation for details. It is too complex to be throughly explained in one comment. `synchronized` Keyword is one of the trickier things in Java and you should take your time to learn it well. (`synchronized(values)` ensures that only one thread accesses the `values` Object at one time. Read the doc for the boundaries of "one time")

Comment: if we use static map, then will there be any issues in multithreading environment? Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 If you use a `static` map but don't care about synchronization, then yes there will be multithreadding issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement number of threads want to execute same logic which is PrintTask. So what's the need to have PrintTask as a thread, why can't it be a simple class (singleton) and pass it to those threads. And make PrintTask thread safe using Lock or synchronized method. So your PrintTask should look like this.

```
class PrintTask {
    private Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
    public synchronized void methodToBeExecutedByThread(String key, Map value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    public Map getMap() {
        return map;
    }
} 


class PrintTaskThread {
    private PrintTask task;
    private String name;
    public PrintTaskThread(PrintTask task, String name) { 
        this.task = task;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
        //populate map as requires
        task.methodToBeExecutedByThread(name, map);
    }
}
```

And I suggest don't use Thread/Runnable as key for the map. Instead gives unique key when you create a thread in your case thread name will do the job . So in case if you want to access map which is being used by a Thread with the name "Thread 1". you can get access to it via `<Object of PrintTask>.getMap().get("Thread 1")`.

Comment: I should not make logic method to be synchronized...All threads should be able to access at a time...

Comment: Why not have a separate instance per thread? Your question remains 100% obscure.